# Mapping problem involving equivalence relations

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $\alpha$ be equivalence relation on the set $A \neq \emptyset$ and $\beta$ an equivalence relation on the set $B \neq \emptyset$. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$. Define the natural map $nat_{\alpha}:A\rightarrow A/\alpha$ and $nat_{\beta}:B\rightarrow B/\beta$ such that $nat_{\alpha}(x)=x^{\alpha}$ for every $x \in A$  and $nat_{\beta}(y)=y^{\beta}$ for every $y \in B$. Prove that there exists a mapping $f^*:A/\alpha\rightarrow B/\beta$ such that $f^*\circ nat_{\alpha}=nat_{\beta}\circ f$ if and only if $a\alpha b \implies f(a)\beta f(b)$.

The idea of the "natural map" itself is quite tricky and honestly I can't even find any remotely similar problems to this one using this type of map.

This is my attempt to get somewhere with this problem:

We need to prove both implications obviously so I started with $f^*\circ nat_{\alpha}=nat_{\beta}\circ f \implies$ $a\alpha b \implies f(a)\beta f(b)$.

Let's assume that $f^*:A/\alpha\rightarrow B/\beta$ exist and also $f^*\circ nat_{\alpha}=nat_{\beta}\circ f$. In that case using definition of compisition and the definition of $nat$ we can simplify it to $f^*(nat_{\alpha}(x))=nat_{\beta}(f(x)) \iff$ $f^*(x^{\alpha})$=$f(x)^{\beta}$.

Similarly we can "simplify" $a\alpha b \implies f(a)\beta f(b)$ to $a^{\alpha}=b^{\beta} \implies f(a)^{\beta}=f(b)^{\beta}$.

I just don't even know how to approach this problem.

Comment: It might help to observe that (pretty much by the definition) $nat_{\alpha}(a) = nat_{\alpha}(b)$ if and only if $a\alpha b$, and that the same thing holds on the $B$ side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have such $f^*$.
Then
\begin{align}
a \alpha b 
&\Rightarrow nat_{\alpha}(a) = nat_{\alpha}(b)\\
&\Rightarrow f^*(nat_{\alpha}(a)) = f^*(nat_{\alpha}(b))\\
&\Rightarrow nat_{\beta}(f(a)) = nat_{\beta}(f(b))\\
&\Rightarrow f(a) \beta f(b).
\end{align}
Conversely, if $a \alpha b$ implies that $f(a) \beta f(b)$, then define $f^*$ by making $$f^*(a^{\alpha}) = f(a)^{\beta}.$$
It is clear that each element of $A/\alpha$ (each equivalence class) has an image.
If $a^{\alpha} = b^{\alpha}$, then $a \alpha b$, whence, by hypothesis, $f(a) \beta f(b)$, that is, $f(a)^{\beta} = f(b)^{\beta}$.
So the image is unique and therefore the map $f^*$ is well defined.

Comment: I wish you wrote this 12 hours ago ;D. I got the exact problem on my exam today and managed to only do the first implication.

Comment: I answer as soon as I saw the question. As you can see, it is easy enough. It happens that sometimes we get stuck with simple things. Good luck for your other exams (and today's one too)!

Comment: @DreaDk By the way, you mentioned you don't know of similar problems (presumably using maps between quotient sets made from ones made from the original sets?). This is quite common in algebra, and you might have found this under a different guise. For example, in groups, when you have a quotient group $G/N$ where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it is related to the equivalence (more, congruence) relation $\theta$ on $G$ defined by $a \theta b$ iff $ab^{-1} \in N$. Then these maps appear in results related to the [Isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).

Comment: That's probably because I'm first year math student and we've never been introduced any abstract algebra/advanced set theory. The educational system is a bit odd here. I'll be looking forward to the things you wrote though! Thanks.